# PHP classes and functions optional arguments

Tags: php

Is this not meant to work in PHP?

```
<?php
function shout($mute="", $message="") {
    echo $message;
}

shout($message = "Boo");
?>
```

I know this is a poor example, but it gets my point across.

Answer (score 2):

No this won't work, function parameter order is strict and cannot be manipulated.

You can either do this:

```
shout(null, 'Boo');
```

Or re-factor your function to accept an array:

```
function shout($args) {
    echo $args['message'];
}

$args = array('message' => 'boo');
shout($args);
```

Comment: `($message = 'Boo') == 'Boo'`. This means, that he will set the local variable `$message`, but will pass the value `'Boo'` as the first argument (`$mute`).

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function shout($mute="", $message="") {
    echo $message;
}

shout(null, "Boo"); //echo's "Boo"
?>
```

You have to pass in the correct parameters in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

in php passing function parameters is conventional,

suppose you have a function definition like this `function myfunc($arg='something or null' , $arg)` this is the wrong way as we have to put our constants on right side of the function like this

```
function myfunc($arg, $arg='something or null'){}
```

when you are calling function make sure you are passing correct arguments i.e `myfunc('test')`

if you described $arg='null' then you dont need to pass anyhing from your function call because null is a value whereas empty string is nothing.

so in your case you must do like this `function yourfunction('value1','value2')`